# regex match and exclude

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am having problems to match and exclude a regex string for Google Analytics.
I want to include all URLs that contains `project/XXX` or `projekt/XXX`, but not URLs that ends with `project`, `projekt`, `signup-open`, or `signup-submit.
From the list below I only want to match the last two in bold.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

- X.se/
- X.se/en/
- X.se/projekt/
- X.se/en/project/
- X.se/projekt/signup-submit/
- X.se/en/project/signup-open/
- X.se/projekt/XXXXX/signup-submit/
- **X.se/en/project/XYXYX**
- **X.se/projekt/YXYXYX**

Comment: the matches should be the last two bullets and non other

Comment: the string with XY can be anything but within /'/

Comment: Does analytics support negative lookahead? `^.*proje[kc]t/(?!signup)[^/]+$`

Comment: It seemed to work but not when I did a Regex-search in GA. Is there any other way?

Comment: Can you use multiple rules and maybe just excluded those? http://www.conversionworks.co.uk/blog/2012/02/20/google-analytics-regular-expression-negative-look-ahead-workaround/

Comment: You need to set up include and exclude filters. GA regex is RE2 based and does not support lookarounds.

Comment: i tried finding what google analytics allows and disallows but cannot find any good answers. It just replies "Your data request includes an invalid regular expression."

Comment: Wiktor, I am configuring goal funnel and cannot use any filters sadly.

Comment: @frenne Use the `@` to tag. Notifications aren't sent otherwise.

Comment: @wiktor, I am configuring goal funnel and cannot use any filters sadly.

Comment: Then you are stuck, I can't imagine a sane no-lookaround expression with such requirements.

Comment: @Wiktor Is there any way to match a string ending with wildcards but excluding a different string?

Comment: You can't use a RE2 regex to match a string that does not contain something and contains something else. Even if it does not contain something. You may only match strings that do not start or end with some pattern. You may add a character restriction, but it will complicate the pattern that will be complicated enough.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Ok. thanks for all the help thought! :)